# How feasible is it to get a B2 visa for a 6-month stay?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

How feasible is it to spend more than 3 months in the US? Here are the most pertinent facts about me:

- European who's been in the US once on a visa waiver in September 2017 for 3 weeks.
- Not employed (living off savings).
- Enough funds to stay for 6 months.
- No properties in Europe.
- Parents and siblings in Europe.
- Would travel in fall and winter, so starting around September 2018.

Comment: There is a question you haven't answered here, and which immigration will want to know - why do you want to stay in the US for six months?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're a citizen of a country eligible for VWP, it is *extremely* likely that you would be issued a standard 10-year B1/B2 visa when you apply at the consulate. With this visa you are eligible to stay in the US for up to 6 months at a time by default. The only catch is that your duration of stay would be eventually determined by the immigration officer who issues your I-94 entry stamp and it's possible that you'll receive a shorter duration when you arrive to the US.

Carry proof of your financial standing and a detailed plan for 6 month to the border - and remember to specifically ask for a 6-month I-94. Given that you've already traveled to the US once you are very likely to get it.